# vmware esxi losing datastore

Tags: hard-drive, datastore, vmware-esxi

My vmware esxi server suddenly freezed this friday. When I looked up, what happend. I figured out lot of these messages in log

```
Device t10.ATA_____WDC_WD10EARS2D00Y5B1
__________________________WD2DWCAV594-
40670 performance has deteriorated. I/O latency 
increased from average value of 9400 
microseconds to 1219195 microseconds.
warning
4.3.2012 20:07:47
host
```

I cant figure out, whether disk is failing or esxi has problems with disk driver.
I am using Asus ASUS M2A-VM 
Disk controller shows on esxi as: SB600 NonRaid 5 SATA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like one of your disks, a Western Digital i'd imagine, may be having physical issues. There are diagnostics available from WD you should probably run against the disk. Might be a good time to take a backup as well.

I sincerely doubt this is an issue with the "driver" as there are little to no configuration options there to be misconfigured.

Answer (score 1):

What version of vSphere? I'm assuming version 5 since this is a new warning to v5.
Take a look at this conversation about the same issue.

http://communities.vmware.com/thread/328081?start=15&tstart=0